# Emulator won't open on Amd E2 1800 CPU

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I have a Lenovo laptop, CPU AMD E2-1800,  Android SDK says your CPU doesn't support vt-x and SVM, SO I **installed an ARM emulator as suggested by others over the internet,  but even after 3 hours, it doesn't get open**. I read somewhere on this website to use blue-stack instead, but the thing is blue-stack doesn't get open when I'm running the Android SDK, an error pops up, says **"insufficient memory"**.

Can anyone help? What to do, should I buy an Intel Cpu just for this?

Operating System: Windows 8.1

[image: AmdCpuImage]

Comment: That chip does support AMD-V (aka SVM). Make sure it's enabled in your firmware settings (BIOS setup). That said, it's not a good chip for development - if programming is a serious hobby, unless you really like waiting, you should really consider buying a more powerful system.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks, i don't like waiting, that explains why eclipse keeps getting hanged. So i have to buy a new system, just changing the CPU wont help?

Comment: Most all laptop CPUs are soldered to the motherboard, so no, you can't just replace it. Also the CPU and chipset are closely coupled, so you basically need a whole new motherboard. And you can't put a different motherboard in a laptop, so yes, you might consider a new Core-i5 or better system.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks,  in Bios Svm is already ENABLED https://ibb.co/bto2Ap any temporary solution for now?